# Replace icon button with URL image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, whatsapp

I would know how to modify the Whatsapp icon button displayed in all pages for start a chat.
In my site I have this code for the function in footer.php:

```
<div class="whatsapp">
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=-------------" target="_blank">    
<h5><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-3x " aria-hidden="true"></i></h5></a>
            </div>
```

The CSS is this:

```
.whatsapp {
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
top: 52%;
}
.whatsapp h5 {
color: white;
background: #20b20f;
padding: 12px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I wanna change the icon (fa fa-whatsapp fa-3x) with an icon that I have upload on my media library (URL image).
Furthermore I would hide the icon in cart and checkout page. How can I make that?
Thanks!

Comment: background-image ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+nnnnnnnnnnnnnn" target="_blank" style="background: none;"><img style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" src="/images/whatsapp_square.png"></a>
```